# Fixed point theorem proof question

Tags: algebraic-topology, vectors

From Massey's Algebraic topology:

> Any continuous map of $E^n$ into itself has at least one fixed point.

The proof starts by trying showing that if there exists a continuous function $f(x)$ from $E^2$ into itself that has no fixed points then $S^1$ is a retract of $E^2$

He then constructs $r(x)$ by drawing a point $x=(x_0,y_0)$ and creating a line from $f(x)$ through $x$, and into $r(x)$ on $S^1$.

He then says that, using vector notation, we can easily write a formula for $r(x)$ in terms of $f(x)$ and uses this formula in the proof, but I have no idea how to write this using vector notation.  I see that $v^{\rightarrow} = f(x) + t(f(x) - x)$ would be a line that will eventually intersect $S^1$, but I don't see how I could write this function so that the final point would be in $S^1$.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to modify your formula for $v$ slightly, writing 
$$
v(t) = f(x) + t (x - f(x))
$$
so that $v(0) = f(x)$ and $v(1) = x$, and as $t$ ranges over nonnegative values, it describes a ray from $f(x)$, through $x$, one that hits the unit sphere at some point, and continues onward.

Writing $u$ for $f(x)$ to simplify things, and $v$ for $v(t)$, if you want $\|v\| = 1$, i.e., you want $v(t)$ to be on the unit sphere, you need $ v\cdot v = 1$, i.e., 
$$
(u + t(x-u)) \cdot (u + t (x-u)) = 1
$$
which turns into
$$
u \cdot u + 2t (x-u) \cdot u + t^2 (x-u) \cdot (x-u) = 1
$$
which is a quadratic in $t$ that has only one positive solution, which is 
$$
t = \frac{ - (x-u) \cdot u + \sqrt{ ((x-u) \cdot u)^2 - 4 \|x-u\|^2 (\|u\|^2 - 1)}}
{2 \|x-u\|^2}
$$

Yeah, it's a mess. But it's the answer you need.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your answer, why do I want $||v||$ to be $1$?  Since $v$ maps $f(x)$ to points on a line, any vector of length $1$ from a point in the interior of $E^2$ shouldn't be within $S^1$.

Comment: If you vary $t$ in your formula for $v$, when $t = 0$ you get $f(x)$; when $t = 1$ you get $x$ (or you would if you changed $f(x) - x$ to $x - f(x)$, which is what I thought you'd written!). So as $t$ ranges from $0$ to infinity, you get a ray from $f(x)$ through $x$ and onwards. There's a particular $t$-value for which $v(t)$ has length $1$, i.e., for which $v(t)$ represents a point on the unit sphere. ("v" wasn't a great choice for a   name. Better, perhaps, would be $v = x - f(x)$, and $L(t) = f(x) + t v$.) Anyhow, the $t$ I showed is the one for which $v(t)$ is a point on the unit sphere.

Comment: Answer edited to reflect that $x-f(x)$ confusion...